# Can we post messages into SOLACE using Spring Cloud stream without configuring a consumer on the queue/topic?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, solace, subscriber

I am trying to post messages into Solace using Spring Cloud Stream without configuring a consumer and I am getting this error "org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers".

When I add a consumer(Sink) on the same queue, then the code works fine.

Why do we need to have a subscriber listening to a queue before we post a message to the queue ?

Code used to connect to Solace

Spring Boot Main Class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@Slf4j
@EnableBinding({SendReport.class}) 
public class ReportServerApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext-server.xml");
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ReportServerApplication.class).listeners(new EnvironmentPreparedListener())                                                   .run(args);
}
```

Class to connect channel to topic:

```java
public interface SendReport {

    String TO_NMR = "solace-poc-outbound";

    @Output(SendReport.TO_NMR)
    MessageChannel output();

}
```

Message Handler:

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@EnableBinding({SendReport.class})
public class MessageHandler {

    private SendReport sendReport;

    public MessageHandler(SendReport sendReport){
        this.sendReport = sendReport;
    }

    @Output(SendReport.TO_NMR)
    public void sendMessage(String request) {
        log.info("****************** Got this Report Request: " + request);
        var message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(request).build();
        sendReport.output().send(message);
    }
}
```

Properties used for configuration : application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    # spring cloud stream binding
    stream:
      bindings:
        solace-poc-outbound:
          destination: TOPIC_NAME
          contentType: text/plain

solace:
  java:
    host: tcp://xyz.abc.com
    #port: xxx
    msgVpn: yyy
    clientUsername: aaa
```

Dependencies used:

```
'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream',
'com.solace.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-solace:1.1.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're asking based on the limited information you've provided.

Spring Cloud Stream defines 3 stereotypes of apps `Source`, `Processor`, `Sink`. What it appears you're describing is the `Source` type application - an application that does NOT *consume* anything and only produces. . ., so I am not sure what consumer you are referring to.
Perhaps you can post your app somewhere on github so we can take a look .
Also, I would recommend looking at [our samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely use SCS with Solace for guaranteed messaging. Like Oleg said, we probably need a bit more information to ensure we give you the correct answer.  From a solace perspective can you share the client-profile and queue information? I gave examples of how to get this info using the solace cli, but you could also get it via soladmin, PubSub+ Manager or via SEMP.

1. Client-profile

   - In order to get your client-profile you'll need your clientUsername from your SCS solace binder config and use that to find your profile.

     - On solace cli `show client-username <username> detail`
   - Get client-profile info

     - On solace cli `show client-profile <profile_name> detail`
2. Queue Info

   - On solace cli `show queue <queue_name> subscriptions`